# Getting the error in while loop '>': No conversion from 'int' to 'int *'

Tags: c, recursion, insertion-sort

I am Using Microsoft Visual Studio to compile the code.  I get this error in the while loop for the condition `a[i] > k`:

> '>': No conversion from 'int' to 'int *'

Here is the code:

```
/* Sort the array using Recursive insertion sort */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void RecursiveInsertionSort(int a[], int);

/* Recursively call the function to sort the array */
void RecursiveInsertionSort(int *a, int n) 
{
    int i,k;
    if (n > 1)
        RecursiveInsertionSort(a, n - 1);//Call recursively
    else {
        k = a[n];
        i = n - 1;
        while (i >= 0 & &  a[i] > k){ 
            a[i + 1] = a[i]; //replace the bigger
            i = i - 1;
        }
        a[i + 1] = k; //Place the key in its proper position
    }
}

/* Main function */
void main()
{
    int a[] = { 5,4,3,2,1 }; // Array unsorted declared
    RecursiveInsertionSort(a, 5);//call recursive function to sort the array in ascending order
}
```

Can anyone please help me understand the error?

Comment: Is that a space between the ampersands?

Comment: thanks..Silly mistake

Answer (score 1):

You have a space inside what should be the logical operator `&&`:

```
while (i >= 0 & &  a[i] > k){
```

This is equivalent to

```
while (i >= 0 & &a[i] > k) {
```

which is a bitwise AND-operation between `i >= 0` and `&a[i] > k` (two boolean values).

The `&a[i] > k` compares the address of `a[i]` (which is an `int *`) with `k` (which is an `int`).  Hence the error.